# SpriteKit: Move Whole Scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, move, scene

I want to add a specific number of squares to a scene. When I do this a part of the square is outside the view. Is it possible to move the whole scene on the y-axis?

Answer (score 1):

I tried and it looks like the scene itself can't be moved. An alternitive approach is to add an SKNode to the scene which represents the whole world. Add all other elements to the world node. Now you can move this node if you want to move the whole scene. I'm working on a short tutorial about that in my Blog. Here's my current code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

// Declare the needed nodes
var worldNode: SKNode?
var spriteNode: SKSpriteNode?
var nodeWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // Setup world
    worldNode = SKNode()
    self.addChild(worldNode!)

    // Setup sprite
    spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    spriteNode?.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    spriteNode?.xScale = 0.1
    spriteNode?.yScale = 0.1
    spriteNode?.zPosition = 10
    self.addChild(spriteNode!)

    // Setup backgrounds
    // Image of left and right node must be identical
    let leftNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "left")
    let middleNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "right")
    let rightNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "left")

    nodeWidth = leftNode.frame.size.width

    leftNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    leftNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    middleNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    middleNode.position = CGPoint(x: nodeWidth, y: 0)
    rightNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    rightNode.position = CGPoint(x: nodeWidth * 2, y: 0)

    worldNode!.addChild(leftNode)
    worldNode!.addChild(rightNode)
    worldNode!.addChild(middleNode)


}


var xOrgPosition: CGFloat = 0
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let xTouchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self).x
        if xOrgPosition != 0.0 {
            let xNewPosition = worldNode!.position.x + (xOrgPosition - xTouchPosition)

            if xNewPosition <= -(2 * nodeWidth) {
                // right end reached
                worldNode!.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                print("Right end reached")
            } else if xNewPosition >= 0 {
                // left end reached
                worldNode!.position = CGPoint(x: -(2 * nodeWidth), y: 0)
                print("Left end reached")
            } else {

                worldNode!.position = CGPoint(x: xNewPosition, y: 0)
            }
        }
        xOrgPosition = xTouchPosition
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // Reset value for the next swipe gesture
    xOrgPosition = 0
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}

Comment: Would it be used like worldNode.addChild(otherNode)

Comment: Yes. I can post a sample later

Comment: Yes, moving the scene is not what you want to do (Although it can be done)  Follow the approach of starting with a master node for all your objects in the scene,  then just move the master node around inside the scene to have all your nodes inside move.  This is a great approach for when you want to add a HUD in the game. you would add your master node to the scene, then your HUD node to the scene, so that when you move your master node,  only those objects attached to the master will move, and the nodes in the HUD will stay static